# Ezdxf library: How to change location of templates\__init__.py in getstream?

Tags: python-3.x, dxf

I am building a desktop program with PyQt5 that generates dxf files. To create dxf file I use ezdxf library. When I run script, no error appears. However, after compilation of program by pyinstaller and running program I get error message:

```
    "Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Outline Generator.py", line 324, in generateDXFfile
    File "DXFgenerator_data_class.py", line 23, in __init__
    File "DXFgenerator_data_class.py", line 44, in loadData
    File "site-packages\ezdxf\filemanagement.py", line 42, in new
    File "site-packages\ezdxf\drawing.py", line 390, in new
    File "site-packages\ezdxf\templates\__init__.py", line 37, in getstream
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI119642\\templates\\AC1024.dxf'"
```

I found the file 'templates' in ezdxf library data, placed it on the same location as program and added change of templates location in code by command  ezdxf.options.template_dir from official documentation like this:

```
path_files = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
work_dir = path_files + '\\templates\\'
for sample in self.samples:
    ezdxf.options.template_dir = work_dir
    dwg = ezdxf.new(dxfversion='AC1024')
    msp = dwg.modelspace()
    dwg.layers.new(name='04 Foil cutout 165W', dxfattribs={'linetype': 'Continuous', 'color': 1, 'lineweight': 0.00})
    dwg.layers.new(name='02_markings', dxfattribs={'linetype': 'Continuous', 'color': 6, 'lineweight': 0.00})
    dwg.layers.new(name='05 alignment', dxfattribs={'linetype': 'Continuous', 'color': 3, 'lineweight': 0.00})
```

Comment: try os.path.join to create work_dir

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. It works only with this command: dirpath = os.getcwd()  if the file AC1024.dxf is placed in the same location as program